# NXP Jennic JN5148 and ZCL home automation profile

Tags: microcontroller, zigbee

Has anyone managed to run the Zigbee Home Automation profile over NXP JN5148?

I've tried but the microcontroller seems to be stuck.

Comment: Are you trying an Application Note from Jennic or did you build your own solution?